# Agregar espacios a un archivo .txt no funciona y agrega comillas "" en C#

Tags: c#

Estoy usando este helper para agregar espacios finales cuando un campo de cierta longitud no completa el length.

```
public string FitSpace(string cadena, int size) {
            var refill =  " ";

            try
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(cadena))
                {
                    return cadena;
                }
                else
                {
                    while (cadena.Length < size)
                    {
                        cadena =  cadena + refill;
                    }
                }
                return cadena;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                return cadena;
            }
        }
```

Al ser un string estoy parseando mis otros campos (int, decimal) a un String.

```
var info= infoView.Select(s => new 
{

    Ventaitemsku = formatterHelper.FitSpace(s.Ventaitemsku, 12), //SKU | Length [12]
    Ventaid = int.Parse(formatterHelper.FitSpace(s.Ventaid.ToString(), 8)), //Transaction Number | Length [8]
    Ventacreacion = s.Ventacreacion.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), // [10]
    Ventaitemcant = s.Ventaitemcant.HasValue ? int.Parse(formatterHelper.FitSpace(s.Ventaitemcant.Value.ToString(), 3)) : 0, //Net Unit Sales | Length [3]
    Ventaitemprecio = decimal.Parse(formatterHelper.FitSpace(Math.Round(s.Ventaitemprecio.Value / (decimal)1.16, 13).ToString(),19)), // Length [19]



    Ventaextid = formatterHelper.FitSpace(s.Ventaextid, 30) // Order Number | Length [30]

}).ToList();
```

Lo que está ocurriendo es que a los campos que SÍ son string (los que no parseo) les está agregando el espacio correspondiente pero también comillas dobles al principio y al final, algo así `Ventaitemsku => "ABCD12345   "`
Y a los que parseo no les afecta en lo absoluto mi helper, lo cual es raro porque si hago el cambio de que en lugar de un espacio " " les agregue un cero(0) o una letra(x) lo hace sin problema.

Lo curioso también es que si tiene que agregar el espacio al principio del campo, tampoco lo hace con los que ya tengo parseados a un string.

¿Alguna ayuda?

Comment: Cuando dices que a los valores que parseas, es decir, aquellos que no son string, no les afecta en absoluto ¿a qué te refieres? ¿Puedes poner ejemplos de entradas y las salidas que esperarías?

También veo que primero parseas valores numerales a string, les añades espacios en blanco y los vueles a parsear a enteros/decimales. Obviamente con este último parseo vas a perder todos los espacios que hayas añadido, por lo que no veo qué buscas exáctamente.

Comment: Por fin resolviste?

Answer (score 0):

En **C#** existen las funciones **PadLeft** y **PadRight**.

La primera rellena la cadena con caracteres por la izquierda y la segunda agrega caracteres por la derecha.

En este ejemplo se agregan 10 espacios al final de la cadena.

```
string txt = "hola";
string nuevoTxt = txt.PadRight(10);
```

También existe una sobrecarga de estos métodos, pero con dos parámetros:

```
string txt = "hola";
string nuevoTxt = txt.PadRight(10, '.');
```

Aquí se rellena la cadena con diez puntos a la derecha.

Revisa esto y adáptalo a tu respuesta.

Comment: Gracias por responder. Desafortunadamente utilizando estas funciones al momento de escribir el archivo los campos no agregan el espacio y si quiero agregar un caracter me marca una excepción/error **{"La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto."}**

Comment: @dannesz, pero a ver hablas de escribir en un fichero y no compartes nada del codigo que tienes para escribir en tu fichero, las funciones que te doy no las invente yo, son del propio .Net y hacen lo que te dije, algo debe faltarte

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda. El problema surgía en tratar de pasar un archivo csv a txt por lo que procedí a utilizar un StringBuilder y crear el archivo txt directamente. Con ese cambio las funciones PadLeft y PadRight me fueron utiles.